# How to access an xml file using a relative path?

Tags: actionscript-3, path, air

I've got an Air app, the end user access it by executing a .exe file that later installs the app.

The app reads and writes an xml file.

- The app starts
- the app reads the xml
- after some time, the user saves the changes he made and writes them to the same xml file.

The thing is, how do I describe the path like that?

I've tried:

- ../file.xml
- file.xml
- /../file.xml
- ../../file.xml

Non seem to work, the file is not found.

(I'm using urlloader to find the file)

Comment: Where is your xml? Are you including the file when you package the app?

Comment: The xml is one level lower than src. It means, a ../ should be the correct path. However, urlloader wont find it. I've ended up using File and it works, but, if anyone knows how to use urlloader correctly, if possible, it would be great.

Comment: There is no problem using URLLoader and relative paths. But your app cannot find it when? When testing in Flash? Or when the app is already installed? Or when?

Comment: Then take a look at your File url property and you'll get the right path. No security sandbox issues with AIR.

Comment: As @Fygo mentioned, make sure the XML file is included in the application package. By default, files included in the "src" folder is included, but not when they're in the parent folder. If you include it, it will likely be in the root of your application directory (`File.applicationDirectory`), however items in this folder are read-only. You may want to move it somewhere else after install to be able to write to it. `File.applicationStorageDirectory ` could be a good fit, for example. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: The xml is not included in the application package, it's an external file. I ended up using File and it works.